# Yii - Add form to results page

Tags: php, yii

n00b at OOP and yii both. Im struggling to understand yii and how it passes variables to views.. I have 1 model that accesses mt db and also a form that i can post a string and checkbox value to be added to the db. The posting and retrieving works fine from the prebuilt pages that gii builds. BUT wan i am wanting to do is to have the form and the 'read' from the db all on the same page. So when a post is made through the form, its added to the bottom of that same page in a 'history' type section.

Cant i just add `<?php $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model)); ?>` to my index page?? Obviously not because i get an error: `Undefined variable: model`.

Model:

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "fb_post".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'fb_post':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $post
 * @property integer $checkbox
 */
class FbPost extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'fb_post';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('post', 'required'),
            array('checkbox', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('post', 'length', 'max'=>255),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, post, checkbox', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'post' => 'Post',
            'checkbox' => 'Checkbox',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     *
     * Typical usecase:
     * - Initialize the model fields with values from filter form.
     * - Execute this method to get CActiveDataProvider instance which will filter
     * models according to data in model fields.
     * - Pass data provider to CGridView, CListView or any similar widget.
     *
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models
     * based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('post',$this->post,true);
        $criteria->compare('checkbox',$this->checkbox);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * Please note that you should have this exact method in all your CActiveRecord descendants!
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return FbPost the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
    <?php

class FbPostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
     * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
     */
    public $layout='//layouts/fbhistory';

    /**
     * @return array action filters
     */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
            'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
        );
    }

    /**
     * Specifies the access control rules.
     * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
     * @return array access control rules
     */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a particular model.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new FbPost;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['FbPost']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['FbPost'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Updates a particular model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['FbPost']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['FbPost'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a particular model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }

    /**
     * Lists all models.
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('FbPost');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Manages all models.
     */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new FbPost('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['FbPost']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['FbPost'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
     * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
     * @return FbPost the loaded model
     * @throws CHttpException
     */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=FbPost::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
     * Performs the AJAX validation.
     * @param FbPost $model the model to be validated
     */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='fb-post-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
<?php
/* @var $this FbPostController */
/* @var $dataProvider CActiveDataProvider */

$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Fb Posts',
);

$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'Create FbPost', 'url'=>array('create')),
    array('label'=>'Manage FbPost', 'url'=>array('admin')),
);
?>

<h1>Fb Posts</h1>

<?php
    $this->render('index', array('mode'=>$mode));
?>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Form needs a model where its data to be posted, you have to create model in controller actionIndex and pass it to index view. Example:

```
class FbPostController extends Controller
{
    ...
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        // Create model
        $model=new FbPost;

        // Process posted form data if any
        if (isset($_POST['FbPost']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['FbPost'];
            $model->save();
        }

        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('FbPost');

        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
...
}
```

Now you can add your code:

```
<?php $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
```

to index view file.

Comment: OK, that worked. But the posts dont actually get added to the db. Am i missing something in the controller?